# lvresize showing incoherent and random final size

Tags: lvm, lvreduce

I'm trying to resize (reduce) a logical volume after having already resized the filesystem on it :

```
lvresize -L 63T /dev/vg_raid/datas
  File system btrfs found on vg_raid/datas.
  File system size (62,00 TiB) is larger than the requested size (1,00 TiB).
  File system reduce is required and not supported (btrfs).
```

Of course that doesn't makes sense : 62T is less than 63T, but more than that, the requested size is marked as 1T when I requested 63T!!! The issue is of course the same when using `lvreduce` instead of `lvresize`.

Anybody ever exeprienced a bug like this, and knows how to fix it?

Here is the output of my `lvm version` :

```
lvm version
  LVM version:     2.03.22(2) (2023-08-02)
  Library version: 1.02.196 (2023-08-02)
  Driver version:  4.47.0
  Configuration:   ./configure CONFIG_SHELL=/bin/bash --prefix=/usr --sbindir=/usr/bin --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --enable-cmdlib --enable-dmeventd --enable-lvmpolld --enable-pkgconfig --enable-readline --enable-udev_rules --enable-udev_sync --enable-write_install --with-cache=internal --with-default-dm-run-dir=/run --with-default-locking-dir=/run/lock/lvm --with-default-pid-dir=/run --with-default-run-dir=/run/lvm --with-libexecdir=/usr/lib/lvm2 --with-systemdsystemunitdir=/usr/lib/systemd/system --with-thin=internal --with-udev-prefix=/usr
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm surprised it even cares about the filesystem when not given resizefs option (which doesn't support btrfs anyways). Does it say anything else when you run it with `-v` or `-vv`?

Comment: Nothing more with `-v` or `-vv` but I've got the answer from the LVM mailing-list. The issue is already solved on this patch not yet available on Arch : https://gitlab.com/lvmteam/lvm2/-/commit/fa496513010976aac21584b5081529b76462f9a9

So it was safe to do it with `--fs ignore` which I did.

Comment: Oh, interesting. Seems that LVM filesystem handling was changed a year ago, and fsadm got deprecated. I wasn't aware of these changes yet.

Comment: So new default behavior seems to be to do nothing when growing LVs (up to you to grow filesystem or not), but do try to shrink filesystems / safety checks when shrinking LVs. And in your case, due to a overflow bug, it thought you were shrinking the LV too much. And thus it ends complaining about unable to reduce btrfs size.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is already solved on this patch not yet available on Arch : gitlab.com/lvmteam/lvm2/-/commit/… So it was safe to do it with

> --fs ignore

which I did.